# Bootstrap 4: close open section when section above is closed

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I've created a report that uses Bootstrap accordion to expand and collapse grouped data. The accordion sections are Monthly, Weekly, Daily, and Services.

```
        <thead style="font-size:12px">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" width="200px">Staff</th>
                <th colspan="2" width="250px">Location</th>
                <th colspan="2" width="250px">Credentials</th>
                <th colspan="4">Number of Services Provided</th>
                <th width="150px">Hours of Direct Care</th>
                <th width="150px">No Shows</th>
                <th width="150px">Unique Clients</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var server in Model.Report)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="175px" colspan="2">@server.Staff</td>
                    <td width="175px" colspan="2">@server.Location</td>
                    <td width="175px" colspan="2">@server.Creds</td>
                    <td width="150px">Face-to-Face</td>
                    <td width="150px">Telemed</td>
                    <td width="150px">Telephone</td>
                    <td width="150px">Video</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color:lightsteelblue;font-size:12px"><td colspan="2">Monthly</td><td colspan="12"></td></tr>
                @foreach (var month in server.Monthly)
                {
                    <tr style="background-color:lightsteelblue;" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" onclick="Update('@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)')">
                        <td width="25px"><span id="p_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">+</span></td>
                        <td width="175px">@month.Month</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@month.Face</td>
                        <td>@month.Telemed</td>
                        <td>@month.Telephone</td>
                        <td>@month.Video</td>
                        <td>@month.Hours</td>
                        <td>@month.NoShows</td>
                        <td>@month.UniqueClients</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="font-size:12px">
                        <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="2">
                            <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;" colspan="2">
                            <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                Weekly
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;" colspan="9">
                            <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var week in month.Weekly)
                    {
                        <tr style="font-size:12px" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)" onclick="Update('p_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)')">
                            <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="2">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    <span id="p_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">+</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.WeekDates
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;" colspan="2">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.Face
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.Telemed
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.Telephone
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.Video
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.Hours
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.NoShows
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightblue;">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)">
                                    @week.UniqueClients
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="font-size:12px">
                            <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="4">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;" colspan="2">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                    Daily
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;" colspan="7">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse g_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var day in week.Daily)
                        {
                            <tr style="font-size:12px" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)" onclick="Update('p_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)')">
                                <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="4">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        <span id="p_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">+</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Date.ToShortDateString()
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Face
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Telemed
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Telephone
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Video
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.Hours
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.NoShows
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:lightskyblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)">
                                        @day.UniqueClients
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr style="font-size:12px">
                                <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="6">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Services
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Date
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Case #
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Appt Type
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Contact Type
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        Duration
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach (var service in day.Services)
                            {
                                <tr style="font-size:12px">
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="6">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;" colspan="2">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                            @service.SvcDate.ToShortDateString()
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                            @service.ClientID
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                            @service.ApptType
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                            @service.ContType
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hiddenRow" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
                                        <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="AA_@(server.ServerNum)_@(month.MonNum)_@(week.WeekNum)_@(day.DateNum)">
                                            @service.Duration
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: All sections]

What I would like to set up is that when any open section above an open section is clicked to close, the lower open section will close also. Currently, when you close any upper section, anything expanded stays open.

[image: Closed top-most section leaves lower sections open]

I have tried using `data-parent`, but it closes all of the sections when I open the Monthly section, so I don't think it will work. I have also tried using JQuery to find the section and trigger the collapse('hide') attribute, but it never seems to fire.

```
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
            alert('Trigger');
        });
    });
```

Just need a step in the right direction!

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to close all tabs and leave opened only clicked one?

Comment: any preview code that explain your problem too?

Comment: You have nested accordions? can you paste minimal actual rendered HTML... that'll make it easier to help

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov, no, what I want to do is close all open tabs nested beneath a tab when it is clicked to close.

Comment: @AkberIqbal Added rendered HTML pics to help explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some more research and coding, I figured out where I was going wrong. I had a js function to change the plus signs to minus signs when the section gets expanded.

```
function Update(val) {
        var ele = "p_" + val;
        var sign = document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML;
        if (sign == "+") {
            document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = "-";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = "+";
        }
    }
```

As Bootstrap only works with jQuery, I ended up with the following:

```
function Update(val) {
        var ele = "p_" + val;
        var sign = document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML;
        if (sign == "+") {
            document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = "-";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = "+";
            var subs = "AA_" + val;
            var list = $('*[id^="'+ subs +'"]')
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if ($(list[i]).is(":visible")) {
                    $(list[i]).collapse('toggle');
                }
                var base = "#p" + $(list[i]).attr("id").substring(2);
                if ($(base).text() == "-") {
                    $(base).text("+");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sure to catch flak for using js and jQuery in the same function, but it works exactly as I need it to. Now when I hit the minus sign on the Monthly section, any Weekly, Daily or Services section closes and the minus sign for that open section is changed back to a plus sign, ready for the next click.